# Google Analytics Keyword shows URLs instead of keywords

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having some trouble with GA reports for one of my sites. Since the beginning of the month, GA is reporting URLs instead of keywords under Traffic Sources > Sources > Search > Organic,  in the "keyword" column.

What can be causing this, and how can I fix it?

--
Additional info:

- Have not set up custom filters in this account.
- I get mixed keywords and URLs in the same "keyword" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same issue I scrutinized my server logs to get to the bottom of this. It seems that most organic searches with the domain as keyword do originate from  google maps (and other google services) - when people click the link in the marker on maps the url is transmitted as the search term.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `"Keyword"` for the primary dimension. You've likely selected `"Landing Page"`.

[image: keyword]

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be it. Keyword is selected, I double checked. Whats more, in some cases I get mixed data: real keywords and urls in the same column (without having chosen a secondary dimension either).

Answer (score 0):

What you are observing is a normally possible scenario. In organic search report, under keywords column, GA will list the search keywords which showed your sites in the search engine result and subsequently led to an incoming traffic.

Let the website which your tracking using analytics be http://www.abc.com . Now assume someone searches , say in google, by giving a full url like http://www.xyz.com instead of just a word like xyz and your site link shows up among the search results. Now if this person clicks on your site link in the search results, then google analytics will log this with a traffic source as `search>organic` and keyword http://www.xyz.com , as used for the search.  Now if the person searches using the keywords http://www.xyz.com + `someword` and your site appears in the search result and the person clicks on it , then in analytics you will see the keyword as http://www.xyz.com `+ someword` which will be combination of url + word. This happens mostly if your site abc.com has some page which links to xyz.com or provides the full link and so your site is also indexed by search engines for searches with that web url.

Comment: Hmm thank you for the interesting though. What wouldn't be consistent with this is that two months ago this wasn't an issue, and now I'm getting 120, 109, 76 hits for different URLs, I can't imagine so many people all of a sudden started using google search as an address bar. Also the key word isn't the xyz.com, its different specific internal urls of my site.